# service.getAllUsers is not a function [arangodb and node.js]

Tags: node.js, arangodb

I study Arango and I want to make a small web service for [this](http://www.ashishblog.com/getting-start-with-arangodb-using-nodejs-nodejs-ejs-arangojs/) tutorial.
Then i use "npm start" and when go to "users" list. Unfortunately i have error:

```
service.getAllUsers is not a function
TypeError: service.getAllUsers is not a function
    at /root/nodeArangoWebApp/routes/users.js:8:10
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/nodeArangoWebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/root/nodeArangoWebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/root/nodeArangoWebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/nodeArangoWebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /root/nodeArangoWebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/root/nodeArangoWebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/root/nodeArangoWebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/root/nodeArangoWebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/root/nodeArangoWebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
```

My code in DataServices.js

```
 '''DataServices.js'''
var Database = require('arangojs');
var db = new Database({url:'http://172.31.0.32:8529'});
db.useDatabase("nodeArangoWebAppDB");
db.useBasicAuth("root", "mypassword");
module.export = {
        getAllUsers: function()
        {
                return db.query('FOR x IN User RETURN x')
                        .then((value) => {return value.all();});
        }
}
```

My code in users.js

```
'''users.js'''
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var service = require('../services/DataServices.js');
    /* GET users listing. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
            console.log("↓↓↓↓ Getting User lists ↓↓↓↓");
    //   geting user list from data Service
            service.getAllUsers().then(
                    function (list) {
                            console.log(list);
    //render userlist view with list if user
                            res.render('userlist', { "userlist": list });
                    },
                    function (err) {
                            console.error('Something went wrong:', err);
                            res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database. " + err);
                    }
                    );
    //res.send('respond with a resource');
    });
    module.exports = router;
```

Please help me. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer is in the error that you include in your question. You're defining a method called `getAllUser` then trying to use `getALLUsers()`.

Comment: @nahanil thank you very much, I changed the file so many times that I made a mistake.
Corrected, but the problem remained: (. Updated post

Comment: `module.exports` - Take note of the "s"

Comment: In your DataServices.js.. Should be `module.exports` otherwise the other scripts that you "require" this in won't be able to access it's methods

Comment: @nahanil yes i did it!  in DataServices.js i must add "s"! Thank you very much! You are right! You are best!